# Null propagated ?.First() vs .FirstOrDefault()

Tags: linq, c#-6.0, null-propagation-operator

After using the null propagation operator a while, I stumbled upon writing a linq clause for selecting a single item. Is there a reason (performance, best practice) not to use ?.First()?

```
MyList?.First();
```

or

```
MyList.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not a question of performance or best practice ; they just don't do the same thing.

`MyList?.First()` will return null if `MyList` is null (`First()` won't even be called thanks to the null propagation operator), and throw an `InvalidOperationException` if it's empty (because calling `First()` on an empty list is invalid).

`MyList.FirstOrDefault()` will throw an `ArgumentNullException` if `MyList` is null (because you can't call `FirstOrDefault` with null), and return null (or the type's default value if it's a value type) if the list is empty.

To handle both cases (`MyList` is null, `MyList` is empty), you can do this:

```
MyList?.FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: So in fact MyList?.FirstOrDefault() might be the preferred choice in my case, thanks for a thorough explanation.

Comment: @jakke.korpelainen: the only problem with this super safe approach is that you have no clue why it's `null`. Was the list `null`, was it empty, was the first element `null`? So it's easy to draw the wrong conclusion or to accept invalid states.

Answer (score 2):

Those two lines simply aren't equivalent.

The first will throw if `MyList` contains no elements, but not if it's null.

The second will throw if `MyList` is null, but not if it contains no elements.